# Batch file that writes another batch file

Tags: batch-file

What I am trying to do is write a batch file that, when a specified answer is made will goto another point and write a batch file that will then be called to run. And if any other answer is made it just goes to another point and follows a series of yes/no answers.

I have made two batch files so far. One just teaching me how to use set and if commands in conjunction. The other is for the problem described above.

Here are the two text files for the batches:

```
@echo off
echo What is your first and last name?
set /p answer
if /i {%answer%}=={Tyler Zieske} (call tyler.bat)
```

The second file (tyler.bat)

```
@echo off
echo Are you from South Dakota?
set /p answer=Yes or No (Y/N)?
if /i {%answer%}=={y} (goto :yes)
if /i {%answer%}=={yes} (goto :yes)
goto :no
:yes
echo Your name must be Tyler Zieske
pause

:no
echo Are you a child?
set /p ans=Yes or No (Y/N)?
if /i {%ans%}=={y} (goto :tyler)
if /i {%ans%}=={yes} (goto :tyler)
goto :zieske
:tyler
echo Your name must be Tyler Zieske
pause

:zieske
echo You must not be Tyler Zieske
pause
```

edit:

Instead of all of that trouble, what if I just copied text from the original batch file into a new batch file?

Comment: You haven't asked a question

Comment: The 2nd batch file could just be a function inside the first that you call.  Are you trying to simulate function calls here, or do you really need to generate a new batch file (a rather advanced topic, I think)?

Comment: well what i want to do is that when "Tyler Zieske" is typed that it puts a batch file onto the computer. The original batch file that would contain the command to write the new batch file would be on a usb

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to ask a question.

But I can guess, that your code does not work as expected.
You can type `Tyler Zieske` but the goto fails.

One of the problems is this line

```
 if /i {%answer%}=={Tyler Zieske} (goto :call
 ffff
```

There isn't a closing bracket.
And you should change `{%answer}` to `"%answer%"` as your variant can't work.
Sample: If the content of the answer is `abc` then it exapnds to

```
 if /i {Tyler}=={Tyler Zieske} (echo test)
```

But this fails, as there is a space after `=={Tyler` and it is interpreted as command and not as part of the compare string.

With quotes the space is escaped and therefore still a part of the compare string.

```
if /i "%answer%"=="Tyler Zieske" goto :myLabel
```

Comment: Just stating that the two @echo offs are the beginning of two different batch files. And I haven't asked a question yet because I don't know what to input after the goto. Also, no insult intended, but I know that the (goto :call) is supposed to be closed off. I just want it to be like: What is your first and last name? When you answer any answer from "a" to "alskdjf;alskdjf;aslkdjfa;slkdf" to "any name" that it will perform a different set of commands than a specified answer like tyler zieske

Comment: But `{%answer%}` will always results in a syntax error, as any answer containing a space is breaking the syntax. Btw. you should open a question just after you know a question.

Comment: What do you mean: "you should open a question just after you know a question?" By that do you mean that is should call another batch file with the next question in it? and so basically what you are saying about `{%answer%}` is that it works, but for it to work with any variable answer, I should put `%answer%`?

Comment: No, the quotes are necessary around `"%answer%` and also `"Tyler Zieske"`. Forget the rest of my sentece, I'm not a native speaker and it's to complicated for me to rearrange it

Comment: Okay. So what about the part for getting the batch file for whenever I input a name i.e. `"Tyler Zieske"`
hit enter
(within the batch file there's a code to make the following happen:
(command to write text)
*writes text into another text file that is saved as a batch file*
*then calls the newly created batch file*
*that batch file then runs*

Comment: I understand what you did above (in your edited post) because in CLI spaces in the syntax of a command aren't read i.e. dir c:\my computer\ would just bring up an error saying the directory could not be found unless I had a folder called "my" in the root directory